# Impossible result after executing a custom MS CRM 8.2 workflow action

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, workflow

The following is a fragment of a custom MS CRM workflow activity:

```
[Input("Input name")]
public InArgument<string> InputName { get; set; }
private string InputNameValue
{
    get
    {
        return InputName.Get(Context);
    }
}

[Output("Success")]
public OutArgument<bool> Success { get; set; }
[Output("Result Message Details")]
public OutArgument<string> ResultMessageDetails { get; set; }

[Output("Integer result")]
public OutArgument<int> ResultInt { get; set; }

private CodeActivityContext Context { get; set; }

(...)

try
{
    ResultInt.Set(Context, -1);
    var query = new QueryByAttribute("my_customentity") { ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("my_customentityid") };
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(InputNameValue))
        query.AddAttributeValue("my_name", InputNameValue);
    OutputId.Set(Context, null);

    var results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities;
    if (results.Count == 1)
    {
        OutputId.Set(Context, results.Single().ToEntityReference());

        Success.Set(Context, true);
        ResultInt.Set(Context, 1);
        ResultMessageDetails.Set(Context, "");
    }
    else
    {
        ResultInt.Set(Context, 2);
        Success.Set(Context, false);
        ResultMessageDetails.Set(Context, "Could not find the specified entity by name.");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ResultInt.Set(Context, 3);
    Success.Set(Context, false);
    ResultMessageDetails.Set(Context, ex.Message);
}
```

Note that the code sets up `ResultInt` to -1 in the first line. No matter what happens afterwards, this output property should always be set to 1, 2 or 3. I've confirmed that output workflow parameters can be set multiple times and overwritten as needed. Also note that an `OutArgument<int>` will, by default, be 0.

However, every once in a while a workflow will fail, and the logs will show that `ResultInt` was... -1, and the expected `OutputId` parameter is null. This is an impossible case also for another strange reason - the queried custom entity record DOES exist in the system. It is as if this code is terminated mid-execution without any warnings. Do note that subsequent workflow steps are being executed as if nothing wrong had happened, with the incorrect outputs as described above. If there was an exception inside the `catch` clause, then that should have been propagated "upwards" and logged in CRM, preventing execution of subsequent workflow steps. When I write that the "workflow will fail" I mean that the empty result from this custom activity is later processed by another step, which cannot use a blank value.

Unfortunately, I'm out of ideas on how to potentially debug this issue. Worse yet, is that this is a very freakish occurrence that cannot be replicated. If this ever occurs then a simple "retry" will yield a correct result.

I could enable maximum tracing on the affected CRM server and hope I manage to get something that would indicate what the issue is, but I was hoping someone else might have seen something similar already. My best guess so far is that something odd happens when the query gets executed by CRM (`service.RetrieveMultiple` call) and for some reason the system flips out and terminates the activity, but I have no idea why that would happen.

Comment: Not impossible.  There is no guarantee that code in a `catch` block gets fully executed (or doesn't in turn throw another exception itself).  A `finally` block is a bit better but is also not 100% guaranteed.

Comment: @Zer0 Of course code in a `catch` statement could, potentially, throw an exception itself. However note what the code is in this case. The `catch` essentially sets up 3 `OutArgument` properties. Is it possible for these to fail? I feel an assumption has to be made here, because if `OutArgument.Set()` can fail, then there's no way to get anything out of this code block.

Comment: There are various other reasons for code in a catch block not to be ran other than exceptions.  I'm just pointing out there is no guarantee it gets run, exceptions or not.  Whether that's the case here I'm not sure, but it's something to keep in mind.  And my first guess as the reason why you're seeing -1.

Comment: @Zer0 OK, can you elaborate? Assuming the process isn't terminated by external factors the only other case I can think of is a `return` inside the `try` section, which isn't used in this scenario.

Comment: Sure, one example is the AppDomain getting torn down.  There are others but I'm half-awake and I'm sure someone smarter than I can point them out.  But suffice to say there are several ways catch blocks don't run.

Comment: @Zer0 Your example is something I'd call an "external factor" in this case. Note this happens in the context of an MS-CRM workflow, so essentially it's outside of my control. I could, sort of, understand if the whole execution chain was in this case broken (i.e. the code fails and further workflow steps are cancelled)... but that's not the case either and subsequent WF steps are running fine.

Comment: True, most of the time catch should work.  I'm also fairly sure there are non-recoverable exceptions.  Though I haven't dived into that in quite some time.  But given what you're seeing I think you'd agree your catch block code doesn't appear to be running.  At least not at first glance.  You could probably test this theory out by doing some type of logging during the catch.  Again I'm not sure this is the issue but it's something to consider.